# How to run cron every 20 minutes but not hour

Tags: linux, unix, cron

How to run cron every 20mins so like this:

00:20, 00:40, 01:20, 01:40 etc all the way but not at :00

What should I put in crontab?

Comment: the crontab file has excellent documentation, use `man -s5 crontab` to view it or take a look here: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5

Answer (score 22):

A line like

```
20,40 * * * * /path/to/job
```

should trigger the job only whenever the minute part of the time is 20 or 40.

If you are putting this in the system's crontab, add a username after that last star.

Comment: Oh it's that easy? I've been trying to figure it out for hours...(feels stupid). I'll go set this up and see how it goes, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Add following line in crontab

20,40 * * * * sh your_script.sh

Answer (score -4):

*/20 * * * * /path/to/script.sh

Comment: That runs on the hour, which the OP specifically says he doesn't want. There's already a correct answer (cHao's).